# Is my knee pain during flexion a tendon issue?

Tags: knees, knee-pain

I am a kickboxer. A few weeks back, I played an unrelated game in a field where I sprinted a lot. When I was finished, my left leg around the knee was really sore.

Now, two weeks later, my left knee hurts a bit, but only on flexion, especially with resistance. Flexion with resistance is not a motion that is commonly done, but think: pulling your foot out of a really tight shoe. That hurts. Extension doesn't hurt at all. Kickboxing and walking cause no problems.

I also noticed as a kickboxer, I almost never perform flexion with resistance at the knee (always pushing outwards -- kicking). So perhaps my muscles/tendons for this movement have simply atrophied, leading to the problem.

**How can I check if my left knee flexion pain is tendinopathy or a muscular imbalance, and what exercises I can do to prevent this from re-occurring?**

Comment: As a marathon runner who constantly plagued by random pains, injuries and discomfort, if I can't diagnose it myself then first place I always go is to a physio/movement coach. I'm unfortunate enough that with my day job I work alongside personal trainers and sports massage therapists so I can always ask. The real danger is following the wrong information, you'll just end up doing strengthening exercises for the wrong muscle groups and you might even make the problem worse... not to mention you could be wasting time that could be better used for actual rehab.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check if my left knee flexion pain is tendinopathy or a muscular imbalance, and what exercises I can do to prevent this from re-occurring?

Seek a doctor who expertise in this, searching medical information on the internet feeds your curiosity but it's dangerous.